# Not Getting expected output for reduceGroup function in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to sum a value based on condition. One variable is adding in both condition and another variable is adding on one condition :

```
val record = file.map(rec => (rec.state,rec.gender,rec.Generated.toInt)).groupByKey(_._1)
    .reduceGroups((a,b)=>{
    var total:Int = 0
    var mTotal:Int = 0
    if(a._2.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("m")){
      mTotal = a._3 + b._3
      total = a._3 + b._3
    }else{
      total = a._3 + b._3
    }
    (a._1,mTotal.toString(),total)
    }).collect
```

I am getting sum for variable total but getting value 0 for mTotal.
Any Idea why I am getting 0.
Sample Data:

```
20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur,224152,F,20,1,0,0,1)
20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur,224152,F,28,1,0,0,0)
20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur,224152,F,38,1,0,0,0)
20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur,224152,F,50,1,0,0,0)
20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur,224152,F,54,1,0,0,0)
20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur,224152,F,72,1,0,0,0)
20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur,224155,m,6,1,0,0,1)
20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur,224155,m,7,2,0,0,2)
20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur,224155,m,8,2,0,0,2)
20150420,Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur,224155,m,9,3,0,0,3)
```

And it would be great If you can provide the link where I can read about function like redugroups, flatmap,sortBy.. etc in depth/detail.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is this condition met `a._2.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("m")`? Can you post sample data?

Comment: yes the condition will met(see 6th row from last)

Comment: And if I am getting zero for ne varibale then why I ma not getting the same for other one

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you want to count how many records have the field "m" (is M/F representing gender)?

I will suggest the following to make your code more readable.

1) Define a case class to hold your data:

```
case class Record(date: Int, bank: String, generated: Int, gender:Char, age: Int, ignore1: Int, ignore2: Int, ignore3: Int, ignore4: Int)
```

Then, lets put the samples into a list:

```
val samples = List(
Record(20150420, "Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur", 224152, 'F', 20, 1, 0, 0, 1),
Record(20150420, "Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur", 224152, 'F', 28, 1, 0, 0, 0),
Record(20150420, "Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur", 224152, 'F', 38, 1, 0, 0, 0),
Record(20150420, "Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur", 224152, 'F', 50, 1, 0, 0, 0),
Record(20150420, "Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur", 224152, 'F', 54, 1, 0, 0, 0),
Record(20150420, "Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur", 224152, 'F', 72, 1, 0, 0, 0),
Record(20150420, "Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur", 224155, 'm', 6, 1, 0, 0, 1),
Record(20150420, "Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur", 224155, 'm', 7, 2, 0, 0, 2),
Record(20150420, "Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur", 224155, 'm', 8, 2, 0, 0, 2),
Record(20150420, "Allahabad Bank,A-Onerealtors Pvt Ltd,Uttar Pradesh,Ambedkar Nagar,Akbarpur", 224155, 'm', 9, 3, 0, 0, 3))
```

Now, we can use a for comprehension, to loop trough the collection, and an if clause to filter the elements that we need. In the end, we apply the `size`function to count the amount of records.

```
val howManyMen = { for (record <- samples if (record.gender.toLower.equals('m'))) yield record }.size
```

In the end, we can print the value:

```
println(s"Found men :$howManyMen") //> Found men :4
```

}

Hope this helps - try to work with structuring your code in a readable way!

Comment: . Yes you are right but I need 3 value as output from map. First is state,second in male count and third is total count of that state

Comment: Please update your question, because it is not very clear what you want to achieve. What is the expected outcome of your computation?